# cannot force deleting files outside of current folder "TypeError: glob pattern string required"

Tags: gulp

I want to clean a folder outside of the current folder using del package. However, I keep getting an error: "TypeError: glob pattern string required".

My gulp file:

```
var buildStyleDir = '../B/build/styles/**/*';//'build/styles';

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    return del([buildStyleDir, {force: true}], cb);
});
```

The folder structure is

```
A
    gulpfile
B
    build 
        styles
```

Do you know why I am getting this error although I am using the global pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
return del([buildStyleDir, {force: true}], cb);
```

to

```
return del([buildStyleDir], {force: true}, cb);
```

Note the closing array bracket location - only around the glob.